# Download Windows Updates Using C#

Tags: c#, windows, c#-4.0, windows-update

Is there any way to download Windows updates programmatically from within a C# application?  I want to manage the installation of updates from within my application.

Comment: It is not a programming question! You should ask this in other stackexchange sites or other forums.

Comment: @Mahdi, looks like a programming question to me.  They're asking how to write software that downloads (and, presumably) installs updates.

Comment: maybe with WMI. or Powershell?

Comment: @Mahdi:I want to do it programmatic.I know I can click on Windows Update!!! but I want to do it and manage it

Comment: So, your question must be : How to download files in c#!

Comment: The Windows Update API is documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387099%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @HarryJohnston:Why don't you answer?

Comment: @Mahdi, downloading updates from Windows Update isn't the same as downloading a file from the web.  For one thing, when downloading from Windows Update you don't know the URL.

Comment: @Mahdi:Windows updates aren't a File.They don't have any static address and Just windows can define that what update in for my windows and what update isn't

Comment: @ahmadali, I'm not sure whether that documentation actually answers your question, since it doesn't mention C#.  Can you use a COM interface from C#?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I think I have to add reference to WUA Come in my Project

Comment: @ahmadali shafiee - You would be correct.

Comment: @HarryJohnston:WUA COM Worked.Answer The Question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922132/use-c-sharp-to-interact-with-windows-update

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Windows Update API is [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387099%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  A quick stackoverflow search has convinced me that you can indeed use COM from C# so this should solve your problem.

I also have some [sample code](http://www.scms.waikato.ac.nz/~harry/wsusupdate.vbs), not in C#, but it may give you a head start in understanding how the interfaces can be used.