# How to test if Windows Server is fully updated? (Trying to create an update/reboot loop script)

Tags: windows, powershell, workflow, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-update

Although I generally use pre-baked images of Windows Servers I occaisionally run into a situation where I have to set one up from scratch and go through the incredibly tedious process of checking for updates, installing them and then rebooting. Many, many, many times.

I am trying to write a simple script to automate this.

The checking and installing updates is straightforward:

```
wuauclt.exe /detectnow /updatenow
```

And the rebooting is just as straightforward:

```
shutdown /r /t 0
```

But what I would like to do is create a PowerShell workflow that continues running after reboot, running the above commands in a loop.

The areas I have not figured out are:

- How to check for whether the updates have completed.
- How to test for no remaining updates available to install (AKA Windows is fully updated and the script can stop).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/7958803/886887 , using scripting is usually preferable to using `wuauclt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an [update searcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to check for pending updates:

```psh
$criteria = "Type='software' and IsAssigned=1 and IsHidden=0 and IsInstalled=0"

$searcher = (New-Object -COM Microsoft.Update.Session).CreateUpdateSearcher()
$updates  = $searcher.Search($criteria).Updates

if ($updates.Count -ne 0) {
  # $updates pending
} else {
  # system up-to-date
}
```

Comment: Dude... it's like you know everything PowerShell.

Comment: Not even remotely. Update management just falls into my area of expertise, since I'm working as a sysadmin.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to check if Windows update has finished and has triggered the 'restart to continue installing updates'. Thanks

Comment: @AirCombat Check for the presence of the registry key [`[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired]`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hansr/archive/2006/02/17/patchreboot.aspx).