# Open "Windows Update" screen and execute "Check for updates" from code C#

Tags: c#, windows-update

I'm building Installer project with C# (.NET 4).
My application need to vallidate that user installed all important updates from "Windows Updates".
I already know how to check if there are important updates which not installed yet and I want to let the user the option to execute "check for updates" operation from button in my App.

I tried to search for simillar posts without success.

Do you have any suggestions for me?

Another question: Do you know how to open "Windows Update" window from code (without checking for updates)?

[image: Windows Updates]

Thanks
Ofir

Comment: For your second question: you could try `Process.Start("wuapp.exe");`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922132/use-c-sharp-to-interact-with-windows-update

Comment: and for the first question you could start: `%windir%\system32\wuauclt.exe /detectnow`

Comment: Wouter Huysentruit, Thanks for your comment. I tried run it through cmd and nothing happens.